# How to transform this repeated code in into a function

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I have a bit of repeated code. I'm trying to check if each sentence in a list of sentences contains a certain word at the beginning. If not, I want it do something and then print the values in a dictionary. Else, I want it to do something else and then print another dictionary.

But I can't figure out how to transform the repeated code in question into a function because I need a variable at the beginning of the first loop inside the repeated code.

Here's my code so far:

```
if not audio_keyword_dictionary:
    for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        keyword_set_inside_dict = set()
        for each_keyword in complete_keyword_list:
            if each_keyword in sentence:
                keyword_set_inside_dict.add(each_keyword)
                keyword_dict[sentence] = keyword_set_inside_dict

    for key, value in keyword_dict.items():
        print(f'{value} - {key}\n')

else:
    for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        keyword_set_inside_dict = set()
        for each_keyword in complete_keyword_list:
            if each_keyword in sentence:
                keyword_set_inside_dict.add(each_keyword)
                keyword_dict[sentence] = keyword_set_inside_dict

                for each_value in audio_keyword_dictionary.values():
                    if each_value in sentences[index - 1] and sentences[index - 1] != '':
                        audio_nested_dictionary[each_value] = keyword_dict

    for k, v in audio_nested_dictionary.items():
        for key, value in v.items():
            print(f'{k} - {value} {key}\n')
```

Here's the function I created:

```
def iterate_sentences(sentences, keyword_list):
    keyword_dict = dict()
    for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        keyword_list_inside_dict = list()
        for each_keyword in complete_keyword_list:
            if each_keyword in sentence:
                keyword_list_inside_dict.append(each_keyword)
                keyword_set = set(keyword_list_inside_dict)
                keyword_dict[sentence] = keyword_set

    return keyword_dict
```

Bu how can I I use it if I need 'index' outside the repeated part?

In this part, to be precise, right after where the repeated part ends:

```
                for each_value in audio_keyword_dictionary.values():
                    if each_value in sentences[index - 1] and sentences[index - 1] != '':
                        audio_nested_dictionary[each_value] = keyword_dict
```

Not sure if it needs to be said, but sentence is a list of sentences that follows a pattern. It begins with a string that contains `audio{positive_number_here}`, followed by another string with actual meaning, followed by another `audio{positive_number_here + 1}` and so on, alternating between the two. The list ends with a string with meaning.

Comment: share an example (short one) of `sentences, keyword_list` and explain what is the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function to get rid of the duplication. Just move the `if` statement.

```
for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    keyword_set_inside_dict = set()
    for each_keyword in complete_keyword_list:
        if each_keyword in sentence:
            keyword_set_inside_dict.add(each_keyword)
            keyword_dict[sentence] = keyword_set_inside_dict

            if audio_keyword_dictionary:
                for each_value in audio_keyword_dictionary.values():
                    if each_value in sentences[index - 1] and sentences[index - 1] != '':
                        audio_nested_dictionary[each_value] = keyword_dict

if audio_keyword_dictionary:
    for k, v in audio_nested_dictionary.items():
        for key, value in v.items():
            print(f'{k} - {value} {key}\n')
else:
    for key, value in keyword_dict.items():
        print(f'{value} - {key}\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

1. Create a class and add your functions to the class. That way, you can set `self.index`, and refer to it later.

```
class SentenceManager:
    def iterate_sentences(self, sentences, keyword_list):
        keyword_dict = dict()
        for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
            self.index = index # set index

            keyword_list_inside_dict = list()
            for each_keyword in complete_keyword_list:
                if each_keyword in sentence:
                    keyword_list_inside_dict.append(each_keyword)
                    keyword_set = set(keyword_list_inside_dict)
                    keyword_dict[sentence] = keyword_set

        return keyword_dict

manager = SentenceManager(...)
manager.interate_sentences()
```

2. Return a tuple from the function, see below for how to consume it.

```
def iterate_sentences(sentences, keyword_list):
    keyword_dict = dict()
    for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        keyword_list_inside_dict = list()
        for each_keyword in complete_keyword_list:
            if each_keyword in sentence:
                keyword_list_inside_dict.append(each_keyword)
                keyword_set = set(keyword_list_inside_dict)
                keyword_dict[sentence] = keyword_set

    return keyword_dict, index # return a tuple as (keyword_dict, index)

keyword_dict, index = iterate_sentences(...) # consume tuple
```